# Minimizing linear objective on intersection of convex sets

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constrained-optimization, nonlinear-programming, projection

Suppose I wish to solve the following optimization problem:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min_{\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n} &\mu^\top c\\
\textrm{subject to} & \mu\in C_1\cap C_2\cap\cdots\cap C_k,
\end{array}
$$
where each $C_i\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set.  Furthermore, I have access to projection operators
$$
p_i(x):=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
\arg\min_y & \|y-x\|_2\\
\textrm{subject to} & y\in C_i.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
**Is there an optimization algorithm that wraps around the $p_i(\cdot)$'s that can find $\mu$?**

---

*Notes:*

- The number of sets $k$ is potentially large.  When I tried to apply standard ADMM tricks to this problem, I ended up needing $O(nk)$ space, which is too much.
- If I add a regularizer $\varepsilon \|\mu\|_2^2$ to the problem, then it looks like projection and I can use a cyclic method like [Dykstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dykstra%27s_projection_algorithm). But I really would like to solve this problem without regularization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this recent paper on an extension of stochastic gradient descent that could be used on your problem:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03760

You could also apply Dykstra's algorithm (or any other algorithm that does alternating projections on convex sets) by setting a target value for $\mu^{T}c \leq \gamma $ and reducing it once feasibility has been achieved.

Comment: Thanks!  This paper seems to justify an algorithm I was hoping would work :-) .  I'll implement it and see how well it works.

Comment: Just implemented and it works great!  If this ends up published some day, of course I'll gladly acknowledge your help.  Thanks so much!